# how to configure Firefox to only allow certain iframe access

Tags: firefox, iframe, web-applications, same-origin-policy

In order to modernize our old web application we changed our frames to iframes.

The web application runs ok with the change, but sometimes errors occur.

Today I had the chance to get to a users desktop and firefox (he has problems) via teamviewer (it's a remote troubleshooting tool, it's is similar to having a vnc session on a remote desktop).

I installed firebug on the remote firefox and tried to log into our web application.

In the console I found the error line:

```
 Permission denied to access property "document".
```

After googling for this I found out that it has to do with iframes and sameorigin policy:

```
 http://davidwalsh.name/iframe-permission-denied
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
```

My question now is:

The user has a current Firefox (version 38 or 39). I did not have the time to ask him about possible changes in his settings. In the short time I had the chance being at his firefox I only saw that he has a lot of addons.

I also have Firefox 39 and I do not have problems with iframes. There must be a setting or addon for this to change.

Can somebody tell me what to change in Firefox in order to tighten the security policies that I also get this error?

Comment: Per the entry on David Walsh's blog, have you tried adding an appropriate X-Frame-Options header to your page? Are you certain that all of the requests are for the same origin, from the perspective of your user's machine?

Comment: Thank you Callahad for your comment. He must have some "special" setting in his Firefox, either by "settings" or by "add-ons", that I do not have. This setting seems to have tighten his iframe policies so, that his JavaScript runtime produced an error. I want to have the same configuration that he has in order to reproduce the problematic behaviour!